# Compatibility of Spring Boot 2.0 and Spring Social

Tags: spring-boot, spring-social

Seems like the latest release version of Spring Boot - 2.0 - is not compatible with any currently available version of Spring Social. Can anyone confirm this?

And if it is really so, can we be sure that a new version of Spring Social compatible with Spring Boot 2.0 will be released at all? In other word, are there any plans to release such a version?